# Insert query executes in MySQL workbench but not in webkit.io

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have this query that runs fine in mysql workbench but shows errors in webkit.io and https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/:

```
INSERT INTO `purchases` (`CarID`, `DriverName`, `CarType`, `CarPlate`) VALUES ('rbJLn8VKqh8Xe6TWvMHF', 'IHatesErrors', 0, @numberPlate := generateUniqueNumberPlate());

SELECT @numberPlate AS "key";

SET @numberPlate = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may stumble across this, the answer was my app connect to the DB didn’t have permission to execute multiple queries at once (this is default behaviour for a connection).

My solution was to create a stored proceadure and lock down the user that calls it from having unrequired permissions, rather than granting the permission to run many queries at once.